Generate a customized ID showing 10 numbers
In Google Sheet, I would like to be able to generate an ID/serial number like this:
0000000000A1
Each incrementation should add 1, like this:
0000000001A1, 0000000002A1, 0000000003A1, etc...
By using a sequence =SEQUENCE(10;1;0;1) it is possible to generate something simple. But I do not know how to change the format to what I am looking for.
It doesn't have to be column/row dependent. I just need in a column, to get a serial numbers/IDs with this specific format.

Use text(), like this:
=sort(text(sequence(42; 1; 0); "00000000A1"))

For this to work, the formula needs an array enabling wrapper such as arrayformula(), index() or sort().
See text().

For some reason I have a hard time finding informations for learning Google Sheet. It must be something very simple.
Thank you very much.

For the 101 on spreadsheet formulas, visit GFCGlobal, Google Workspace Learning Center and Google Sheets function list.
